# Best way to conditionally add to a list scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I need to create a sequence in which elements are added conditionally but cannot use `for -> yield` because a certain cleanup task must be executed before the iteration is complete. For example consider the following snippet.

```
sequence.flatMap( msg => {
        val (_, value) = msg
        val returnVal = BaseData(value) match {
          case Some(baseData) =>
            //some processing
            //will return some value here
            Seq("")
          case None => //Do nothing skip this
            Nil //Don't want to add anything here.
        }
        if(!sequence.hasNext){
          //cleanup
        }
        returnVal
      }
```

However this seems very ugly considering I have to create a sequence every time for single objects. Is there a better more functional way to attain this. My output always has to return a `Seq[R]` where `R=String` in my example.

Comment: Why cleanup cannot be done outside the iteration?

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what the point of your code is. But it seems a better fit for foldLeft rather than (flat)Map.

Comment: Looking at the given example, as `sequence.hasNext` will only be true after the loop is finished so you can also call the cleanup code after the loop. Might be that the example misses something important ?

Comment: @nyavro Because this will be lazy evaluated. I guess this link should explain it better : http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201407.mbox/%3CCAPH-c_O9kQO6yJ4khXUVdO=+D4vj=JfG2tP9eqn5RPko=dRNAg@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: So, cleanup should run at each element, not the last one

Comment: @nyavro It is already running on each element.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I think you are right! Should certainly make it look better atleast.

Comment: @Sohaib, no, clean up only happens when sequence.hasNext is false, which is on the last one?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Yes of course. I only meant that the if condition is executed each time.